# Linear system $Ax=y$ with partially known $x,y$ and non singular $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, physics, electromagnetism

**PHYSICAL INTUITION**

While proving the equivalence between the **Dirichlet problem** (i.e. the potential is known on the surface of every conductor) and the **mixed problem** (i.e. the potential is known on some conductors and the charge is known on the remaining ones) for conductors in stationary conditions I stumbled upon the following problem:

> "Let us assume that we have already established that for an isolated system of conductors $\{c_j\}_{j=1,...,N}$ the following is true:
> $$ Q = CV $$
> where $Q=(Q_j)_{j=1,...,N}$ and $V=(V_j)_{j=1,...,N}$ are the vector representing the potentials and the charges on the conductors and $C$ is known as the *capacitance matrix* and it is invertible.
> Now, suppose that, WLOG, $(Q_j)_{j=1,...,M}$ and $(V_j)_{j=M+1,...,N}$ for $M \in \{1,...,N\}$ are known and find the remaining components of both vectors."

**MATHEMATICAL PROBLEM**

This problem can be stated more generally in the form of a theorem:

> "Let us consider the linear system
> $$Ax=y$$
> where $A$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix with complex entries and thus $x,y$ are $n$-th tuples of complex numbers; let us also introduce the following notations:
> $$x_1 \equiv (x_j)_{j=1,...,m}, \hspace{2mm} x_2 \equiv (x_j)_{j=m+1,...,n}$$
> $$y_1 \equiv (y_j)_{j=1,...,m}, \hspace{2mm} y_2 \equiv (y_j)_{j=m+1,...,n}$$
> $$ 
> A = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> B & C\\
> D & E
> \end{pmatrix},
> \hspace{2mm} B\in \Bbb C^{m\times m}, C\in \Bbb C^{m\times (n-m)}, D\in \Bbb C^{(n-m)\times m}, E\in \Bbb C^{(n-m)\times (n-m)}
> $$
> where $m\in \{1,...n\}$.
> Now, suppose that $x_1,y_2$ are known and show that there exist unique $x_2,y_1$ such that the system is satisfied."

**ATTEMPT AT A SOLUTION**

I tried to write out the multiplication of $A$ by $x$ by making use of the blocks in order to obtain, after proper rearrengement, a linear system where $(x_2,y_1)$ is the unknown vector and the rest is given. The result is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{m\times m} & C\\
O_{(n-m)\times m} & E
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-Bx_1\\
y_2 - Dx_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $I$ and $O$ denote the identity and null matrices respectively, with the order being specified by the pedices. Unfortunately the new matrix of coefficients is not necessarily invertible; indeed there is a counterexample to the previously stated theorem by taking:

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

because in this case we end up with $y_1 = x_2$. Nevertheless, there exists a sufficient condition for the theorem to be true: if the columns of the matrix obtained by adjoining $C, E$ vertically generate $\text{span}(e_j)_{j=m+1,...,n}$ (where $e_j$ is the $j$-th vector of the canonical basis of $\Bbb C^n$). In fact, in this case, the new matrix of coefficients becomes invertible. However this condition is not necessarily satisfied by the capacitance matrix.

---

I would like to know if there is a **necessary and sufficient condition** for the theorem to be true. Also, it may be worthwile to notice that the capacitance matrix is symmetric and has positive entries; in fact, I expect the theorem to be true for that matrix  because the solution to the mixed can be proved to be unique indipendently from this result.

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments by @Anne Bauval, $E$ being invertible is a necessary and sufficient condition. Indeed it is easy to see why it is sufficient, while the necessity follows from the fact that otherwise we could choose $y_2$ so that $Ex_2 = y_2 -Dx_1$ has no solution. The only thing that remains is verifying that the capacitance matrix satisfies this condition. I thought about it for some time now and I guess it could be true if the submatrix $E$ could be identified with the capacitance matrix of the system of last $(n-m)$ conductors, in which case it must be invertible.

Comment: The condition is: $E$ is invertible.

Comment: @AnneBauval I guess you are right and this is the necessary and sufficient condition. Still, I do not see how this solves the problem for the capacitance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subscripts, give each partition a distinct name
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\m{B&C\\D&E} \cdot \m{w\\x} &= \m{y\\z} \\
}$$
and solve for the unknown $x{\rm\;and\;}y$ partitions.

First, solve for $x$
$$\eqalign{
z &= Dw + Ex \\
x &= E^{-1}\LR{z-Dw} \\
}$$
then solve for $y$
$$\eqalign{
y &= Bw + Cx \\
  &= Bw + CE^{-1}\LR{z-Dw} \\
}$$
The invertibility of $A$ and $E$ are related via
the [Schur complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)

Mathematically, it is only necessary that $E$ be invertible to solve for $x{\rm\;and\;}y$.

The invertibility of $A$ is not required (but is enforced by the underlying physics).